# How to make one column fixed and the other one scrollable

Tags: html, css, django

I have tried to make a page where one column is fixed and the other one is scrollable. In the template "Os name" and "{{ i.os_name }}", I want to make it fixed. All the other ones should be scrollable.

I have tried some solutions but I'm facing issues. I have pasted the CSS which I have tried. Please tell me where I am going wrong so I can make it correct.

```
<div>
                    <table class="table accountTable" id="book-table" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 91%;">
                        <thead>
                        <tr class="accountBorder">
                            <th class="osfix">Os Name</th>
                            <th class="">Browser</th>
                            <th>IP Address</th>
                            <th>Location</th>
                            <th>Session Time</th>
                            <th>Activity</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            {% for i in account %}
                                <tr>
                                    <td><div class="osfixName">{{ i.os_name }}</div></td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class = "title_elipses accordion">{{ i.browser }}</div>
                                         <div class="panel" style="display: none;"><p>{{i.browser}}</p></div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div>{{ i.ip_address }}</div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div>{{ i.city }}, {{ i.country }}</div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                    {% for key,value in some_date.items %}
                                    {% if i.id == key %}
                    <!--                here we are displaying the age of the ad -->
                                    <span class="dealpagetext">{{ value }}</span><br>
                                    {% endif %}
                                    {% endfor %}
<!--                                        <div>{{ i.last_loggedin }}</div>-->
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        {% if i.activity == 1 %}
                                        <div><a href="/Logoff_p/{{i.id}}">Signout</a></div>
                                        {% else %}
                                        <div></div>
                                        {% endif %}
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                            {% empty %}
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="7" class="text-center">No History</td>
                                </tr>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
```

**css**

```
#book-table {
    width: 131% !important;
    margin-left: 111px;
}
.osfix {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #ddd;
    padding-left: 4px;
}
.osfixName {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    padding-left: 4px;
    z-index: 88;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Please add the relevant tag for whichever templating language you use (The `{% ... %}` and `{{ ... }}` parts)

Comment: use position:sticky instead fixed:  `tr>:first-child {position:sticky;left:0;}` should be enough.

Comment: I have used as you suggested ".osfix {position:sticky;left:0;}". But still it is scrolling